# ServiceStack cookie value not same session id in Redis cache

Tags: session, cookies, servicestack

I have configured AuthFeature with CustomUserSession and use RedisCache as User Auth Repository. And then I use C# JSON service client to authenticate service, authen OK but session ID store in cache does not same as cookie value.

Cookie: ss-id => **I0ZIuzLijch3IY9Tut0z**

Cache: urn:iauthsession:**brSXBQPjmIB6Srv6EPCv**

Please help !
Update ...
Below code use JsonServiceClient:
  `using (var client = new JsonServiceClient("https://api.futabus.vn/api"))
                    {
                        var lRes = client.Post("/auth/credentials", new
                        {
                            UserName = user.UserName,
                            Password = user.Password
                        });
                    }`

BUT when i post direct to https://api.futabus.vn/api/auth/credentials then cookie value same as session id in response object and in cache.

Answer (score 0):

This contains nowhere near enough info to identify the issue, you should at a minimum show the HTTP Headers and code used to make the request.

But the session key is derived from the sessionId if it's not using `ss-id` then you're likely authenticating with `RememberMe=true` in which case ServiceStack stores the [User Session against the ss-pid Cookie instead](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Sessions). If it's not then double-check the HTTP Headers as the Cookie you think is being sent is likely not the one being sent.

Answer (score 0):

I have 3 applications:
1. Main website: example.com
2. User website: id.example.com
3. API: api.example.com. All cookies restrict to the first (1) website (root domain)
All websites have been written with ServiceStack Framework 4.0.

When i call Authentication from the second (2) to api.example.com using JsonServiceClient then:
the cookies store in the first (1) and cookies i get as soon as call authentication are different. 
I think cookies store in the first (1) have been encrypted.
The first (1) using Form Authentication with machine key settings in web.config
Anyone else have idea?